# Add Values to a Range Based on Another Range's Row Number

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a way to generate a list based on the value of each row in a given column (G).  Currently the list can copy entire rows and works perfectly.  It pulls all rows if column G contains the required text ("Card") and puts them in a list on another spreadsheet with no gaps.

**The problem is that I want the list to only contain information from a few columns in each row containing "Card", not the whole row.**

Is there a way to make my macro pull the information only from columns "A", "G", and "ET"?

The code I am currently using is below:

```
'----Alonso Approved List Generator----'
Sub AlonsoApprovedList()
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim NewRange As Range
  Dim MyCount As Long
  Dim ExistCount As Long
  ExistCount = 0
  MyCount = 1
'----For every cell in row G on the ESI Project Data sheet----'
  For Each cell In Worksheets("ESI Project Data").Range("G6:G5000")
  If cell.Value = "Card" Then
      ExistCount = ExistCount + 1
      If MyCount = 1 Then Set NewRange = cell.Offset(0, -1)
      '----Sets up a new range to copy all data from the row if column G in that row contains the value in question----'
      Set NewRange = Application.Union(NewRange, cell.EntireRow)
      MyCount = MyCount + 1
  End If
  Next cell
  If ExistCount > 0 Then
      NewRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Alonso Approved List").Range("A3")
  End If
End Sub
```

**So in short I want to modify the code above to take data from one worksheet and generate a list in another given the row number from the "cell" range and specific columns.**

Column G drop down data validation lists containing one of the following items:

> Card Mortgage Auto Retail Commercial Investment Advisors Collections Operations Information Technology Community Affairs HR Marketing Property Executive Finance Risk Credit Sourcing Staff Admin RCC

Is that possible?

It would be really nice if I could use something like the match function to determine the columns to use by their title.

**To clarify, this spreadsheet is updated regularly by multiple different users so the information is not static.  Rows are added and changed frequently and occasionally deleted.  As such I cannot just copy cell values from the original sheet to the new list.**

Question responses:

1. Column G drop down data validation lists containing one several items. A complete list is in a different worksheet. Users go in to each line item and select from a specific category.
2. The other columns in question contain a line item's name, category (same as column G), a monetary value, and a date.
3. I am hesitant to upload data because much of it is company information. My goal is to have a macro automatically copy multiple cells from the same row to another sheet. The looping and detection of correct rows is already there. Basically, is there a way to replace "cell.EntireRow" (copying the whole row) with a few select rows in that cell?

Comment: You can simply copy the `cell value` in that case. Can you show us some saple data in your `Row in A, G, AT` please? And welcome to SO `=)`

Comment: The problem with just copying the cell value is that I want it to be a part of the for loop and copy the cell value for each row that contains "Card" in column G.  I can't just say copy the contents from A3, A6, and A9 to Sheet2's A1, A2, and A3 because I do not necessarily know which rows will contain "Card".

Comment: @user2033889 in that case data sample will be extremely helpful

Comment: Why exactly is data necessary?  I am hesitant to upload data because much of it is company information.  My goal is to have a macro automatically copy multiple cells from the same row to another sheet.   The looping and detection of correct rows is already there.  Basically, is there a way to replace "cell.EntireRow" (copying the whole row) with a few select rows in that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to come back and update this quesion with an answer.  It is a bit delayed but an answered question is better than a permanently open question...

```
Sub ApprovedList()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rngDest As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim arrColsToCopy

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 5)
    '----For every cell in row G on the ESI Project Data sheet----'
    Set rngDest = Worksheets("Alonso Approved List").Range("A3")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In Worksheets("ESI Project Data").Range("G6:G5000").Cells

        If cell.Value = "Card" Then

            For i = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)
                With cell.EntireRow
                    .Cells(arrColsToCopy(i)).Copy rngDest.Offset(0, i)
                End With
            Next i

            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row

        End If

    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```